# Django Testing: DatabaseCreation' object has no attribute '_rollback_works'

Tags: django, django-testing

I have written a example test and I'm trying to run it without creating a new database every time.

The first time I run my test everything is ok (takes sometime due to building the DB):

```
> REUSE_DB=1 python manage.py test contacts
Ran 1 test in 0.251s
```

The second time I get the following error:

```
> REUSE_DB=1 python manage.py test contacts
nosetests --verbosity 1 contacts
AttributeError: 'DatabaseCreation' object has no attribute '_rollback_works'
```

**Why and how do I solve? Thanks.**

My Test:

```
class ExampleTestCase(TestCase):

def test_contact_page(self):
    resp = self.client.get('/contact/single/')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'django_nose',
)

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: is there `south` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Then try setting `SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE` to `False` ([docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#south-tests-migrate)). Hope this is it.

Comment: @alecxe I have added SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False to my settings now but still get the same error, anymore ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: Yup. Temporary remove `south` from `INSTALLED_APPS` to see if it is actually relevant. And, are you using sqlite? What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Just use nose from github and you're good to go! I belive this is your issue:

https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose/pull/95

I came across this a long while ago, it is now fixed on the github master, but unfortunately django-nose is not updated on pypi since last year..

Comment: I can confirm that the same problem as OP disappeared upgrading django-nose from 1.1 to 1.2